# How to use function to add geom_rect objects to ggplot from a data frame

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create a composite plot in r, the code for which is below:

```
    #Adding initial data
ggp <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x = date, y = covid)) + 
  geom_spline(data = onsdf, 
              aes(x = date, y = covid, colour = "ONS Modelled Estimates"), nknots = 90, size = 1.3) +
  geom_spline(data = gvtdf, 
              aes(x = date, y = covid, colour = "Gvt Reported Positive Tests"), nknots = 90, size = 1.3) 

#Creating function to add stringency bars
barfunction <- function(date1, date2, alpha){
  a <- annotate(geom = "rect",
                xmin = as.Date(date1), xmax = as.Date(date2), ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, alpha = alpha, fill = "red")
  return(a)
}

#Adding lockdown stringency bars
ggp <- ggp + 
  barfunction("2020-05-03", "2020-06-01", 0.5) +
  barfunction("2020-06-01", "2020-06-15", 0.4) +
  barfunction("2020-06-15", "2020-09-14", 0.3) +
  barfunction("2020-09-14", "2020-11-05", 0.3) +
  barfunction("2020-11-05", "2020-12-02", 0.5) +
  barfunction("2020-12-02", "2021-01-06", 0.4) +
  barfunction("2021-01-06", "2021-03-29", 0.5) +
  barfunction("2021-03-29", "2021-04-12", 0.4) +
  barfunction("2021-04-12", "2021-05-17", 0.3) +
  barfunction("2021-05-17", "2021-07-19", 0.2) +
  barfunction("2021-07-19", "2021-12-08", 0.1) +
  barfunction("2021-12-08", "2022-02-24", 0.2) +


#Adding plot labels
ggp <- ggp + labs(title = "Estimated Total Covid-19 Cases vs Reported Positive Cases", 
       subtitle = "From ONS and HMGvt datasets", 
       x = "Date (year - month)", y = "Covid Levels") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2020-05-03", NA ))) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Measurement Method",
                      values = c("ONS Modelled Estimates"="purple", 
                                 "Gvt Reported Positive Tests" = "blue"))
```

The output of this code looks like this:

[Rendered graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDZUm.png)

As you can see, I have a very repetitive function (barfunction) in this code that I would like to change. I thought the best way to do this was to convert the data barfunction() was applying to the graph into a dataframe, and then try to use a function on said data frame. Here is a head of the data frame (called strindf)

```
date1       date2       alpha
2020-05-03  2020-06-01  0.5
2020-06-01  2020-06-15  0.4
2020-06-15  2020-09-14  0.3
2020-09-14  2020-11-05  0.3
```

I initially tried to use apply() to add the strindf data to my plot, however I got an error message (Error in as.Date(date2) : argument "date2" is missing, with no default). Here is how I implemented it into the original code

```
ggptest <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x = date, y = covid)) + 
  geom_spline(data = onsdf, 
              aes(x = date, y = covid, colour = "ONS Modelled Estimates"), nknots = 90, size = 1.3) +
  geom_spline(data = gvtdf, 
              aes(x = date, y = covid, colour = "Gvt Reported Positive Tests"), nknots = 90, size = 1.3) +
  apply(strindf, MARGIN = 1 , barfunction) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2020-05-03", NA ))) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Legend",
```

I'm quite new to r so I'm a bit stumped, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was right. But you have chosen the wrong function from the `apply` family of functions. As you have a function of multiple arguments use `mapply` or as I do below `purrr::pmap`:

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggformula)

barfunction <- function(date1, date2, alpha) {
  annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = as.Date(date1), xmax = as.Date(date2), ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, alpha = alpha, fill = "red")
}

ggplot(NULL, aes(x = date, y = covid)) +
  geom_spline(data = df, aes(colour = "ONS Modelled Estimates"), nknots = 90, size = 1.3) +
  purrr::pmap(strindf, barfunction) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2020-05-03", NA))) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    name = "Measurement Method",
    values = c(
      "ONS Modelled Estimates" = "purple",
      "Gvt Reported Positive Tests" = "blue"
    )
  )
#> Warning: Removed 123 rows containing non-finite values (stat_spline).
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day"),
  covid = runif(366)
)

strindf <- structure(list(date1 = c(
  "2020-05-03", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-15",
  "2020-09-14"
), date2 = c(
  "2020-06-01", "2020-06-15", "2020-09-14",
  "2020-11-05"
), alpha = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -4L
))
```